# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para no repetir esto por 100 preguntas que tengo?

Tags: php, bucle-for, variables, condiciones

```
if ($pregunta1 == "NEVER") {
    $p1 = 0;
} elseif ($pregunta1 == "LESS OFTEN") {
    $p1 = 1;
} elseif ($pregunta1 == "MORE OFTEN") {
    $p1 = 2;
} elseif ($pregunta1 == "OFTEN") {
    $p1 = 3;
}

if ($pregunta2 == "NEVER") {
    $p2 = 0;
} elseif ($pregunta2 == "LESS OFTEN") {
    $p2 = 1;
} elseif ($pregunta2 == "MORE OFTEN") {
    $p2 = 2;
} elseif ($pregunta2 == "OFTEN") {
    $p2 = 3;
}

$suma1 = $p1 + $p2;
```

Hola, como puedo hacer para no tener que repetir este if por 100 ya que tengo 100 preguntas a las cuales asignarles estos valores.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if ($pregunta[$i] == "NEVER") {
        $p[$i] = 0;
    } elseif ($pregunta[$i] == "LESS OFTEN") {
        $p[$i] = 1;
    } elseif ($pregunta[$i] == "MORE OFTEN") {
        $p[$i] = 2;
    } elseif ($pregunta[$i] == "OFTEN") {
        $p[$i] = 3;
    }
}
```

Estuve intentando con un for pero la mera verdad que no se nada de programación estoy aprendiendo algo =)

Comment: Convierte ese código en una función que reciba como parámetro la pregunta, y que te devuelva el número según el valor. Si las respuestas son esas, entonces mejor que las asignes a constantes al principio de tu código y uses esas constantes en lugar del texto al comprobar los ifs

Comment: Gracias estuve tratando con un for pero no se nada de programación =(

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: estuve intentando ponerlo de varias formas y no me permitia :(

Comment: Intenta escribir el código directamente. Si no lo puedes arreglar correctamente, no te preocupes, algún moderador o miembro con reputación lo arreglará por ti.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el típico caso a resolver mediante un array.

La preguntas tendrían en el array un índice, partiendo desde `0`  que es el valor que te interesa para la suma, a saber:

```
    0 => "NEVER", 
    1 => "LESS OFTEN", 
    2 => "MORE OFTEN", 
    3 => "OFTEN"
```

Y así sucesivamente.

Con `array_keys` puedes buscar el índice de un valor dado y hacer la suma.

Veamos un ejemplo, para hacer el código más portable definiremos una función que reciba las preguntas (en un array), busque en `$allAnswers`  y vaya sumando.

```
function sumar($mData) {
    $allAnswers=array("NEVER", "LESS OFTEN", "MORE OFTEN", "OFTEN");
    $total=0;
    foreach ($mData as $row) {
        $total+=array_search($row,$allAnswers);
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Este código es totalmente portable, veamos varias pruebas:

```
#Ejemplo con variables
$pregunta1="NEVER";
$pregunta2="LESS OFTEN";
echo sumar( array($pregunta1,$pregunta2) ).PHP_EOL; #1

#Ejemplo con valores directos
echo sumar( array("OFTEN","MORE OFTEN") ).PHP_EOL;  #5

#Ejemplo con un valor "fake"
echo sumar( array("FAKE","MORE OFTEN") ).PHP_EOL;   #2

#Ejemplo con tres valores
echo sumar( array("NEVER","MORE OFTEN","LESS OFTEN") ).PHP_EOL; #3
```

Comment: Yessss muchas graciasssss   ya quedo ese form.....